# Python 3 - Django 1.7 on Win 8 - MySQL connect issue

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to connect MySQL through Django.

I have Python 3
Django 1.7
OS: Windows 8

MySQL 5.6.12

I have installed MySQL driver from 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
This one - mysql-connector-python-1.1.4-py3.3

Created new project using:
django-admin.py startproject

Created new db: mysite

changed db settings in settings file like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysite',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

when I run python manage.py migrate

I am getting this error:
 File "D:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in check_ready
   raise RuntimeError("App registry isn't ready yet.")
RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.

Please help me or give me some pointers?

Comment: What makes you think this is a MySQL connection issue? The error message doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: My app works when I use sqlite3 DB and throws above error when I change it to MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the release docs for django 1.7?
http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.7.html#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-7

It states that you will get that error if:

- you start using models before everything has loaded (ie. you have code somewhere at the module level that uses models). This is how I came across this problem.
- You have a standalone python script that uses django (instead of a management command). This is an easy fix - just add 'django.setup()' to the script.

EDIT: I forgot to mention - there's also a good chance that the above changes have messed with other INSTALLED_APPS. For instance, django-tastypie is now broken with the latest development version of django. There's a good chance south is broken too.

Comment: yes I did check it, but I am using it in Djamgo project - just created the project and with SQlitw3 it works fine and as soon as I change DB to MySQL I get above error, couldn't understand which Installed app has been changed? or what has changed in the workflow which was the reason for this error.

Comment: Should I switch to Django 1.6 version,if so, how to un install version 1.7?

Comment: Ah, ok. That's not so straight-forward then. ;p

Yeah, I'd try the current stable version. To install it (I'm assuming you're using pip, let me know if not):

    pip install 'django<1.7'

Comment: got 1.6 and after that used pip to install mysql-python and getting this error: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat it is turning out a nightmare for me :( it is already 12:30 am here in London, got to go to bed :(

Comment: Sounds like it's having problems finding a compiler for mysql-python. You might want to look at a precompiled package for python-mysql: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Comment: Ok Let me explain, I have Python 3.3 and I downloaded this from above link MySQL-python-1.2.5.win-amd64-py2.7.exe as it says for 2.7 so in registry I changed the key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\3.3 to 2.7 to pretend and the tool ran itself and installed it.

Comment: after that I tried to run the server or syncdb and both time got error Error loading MySQLdb module: DLL load failed -- when looked at the solution it was saying to run -- pip install mysql-python -- which I did and got following message: -- : 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in d:\python33\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: it suggested to upgrade did that and got this message -- D:\Documents\python\mysite2>pip install mysql-python --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: mysql-python in d:\python33\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up... MEANS I m going in circles and noone is there to help me, bloody installed VS studio 8, 10 everything, looks like my laptop is going to be a mess, PLEASE someone help me and point me in right direction, I dont understand WHY Python made this not easy to use all DB's?

Answer (score 1):

OK, now this is working, had to do lots of things but the thing that worked is:

Installed Python2.7 and changed the path to use it in lace of Python 33

I think the issue was Python 33 was for 64 bit and 2.7 installed as 32 bit and ran the exe file from here
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

which let me use it MySQL which was installed with WAMP server.

did lots of things so I might have missed some, but Python 3.3 is still broken

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the missing app in "INSTALLED_APPS" (settings.py).

Comment: Please see my comment on above post, I am using the same code ecept the database connection is different

Comment: Now downloaded Django 1.6 and when trying to ru pip install mysql-python and getting this error: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 0):

i do it like that:
down:

https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/

stup it
in `__init__.py` you must insert this:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

ok flish!

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you fixed your line breaks (add two spaces to the ends of a line that you want a linebreak to follow) and fixed your typos. I would edit it myself if I knew what you meant by "stup it in" and "ok flish!"

Comment: You may also want to format your code. For help with this, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks